Unexpected error when using srt sockets (<srt/srt.h>)
I have server and client connection with srt socket (by Haivision https://github.com/Haivision/srt).
The connection is established as expected, but then, when communication begins, an odd error appears.
My packet structure is-
width: 2 bytes
height: 2 bytes
image: widthheight3 (3 bytes, rgb, for each pixel)
when trying to receive the first 2 bytes representing the width, I get this message printed in the console:
"LiveCC: buffer size: 2 is too small for the maximum possible 1316"
I could not fix that problem, it's crusial for the code flow to read the first 4 bytes before the rest of the data, but the srt just does not seem to be able to handle smaller amounts then 1316 bytes, and I don't know way. If anyone understats more about the protocol implementation and could help me work it out, that would be great.
here's my code that fails:
// _sock is the srt socket
typedef std::vector<Pixel> Image;

Image Viewer::receiveImage(uint16_t& width, uint16_t& height)
{
    int receivedBytes;
    char buffer[sizeof(uint16_t)];
    
    receivedBytes = srt_recvmsg(_sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); // here the error gets printed
    width = static_cast<uint16_t>(*buffer);
    receivedBytes = srt_recvmsg(_sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); // here the error gets printed
    height = static_cast<uint16_t>(*buffer);

    Image image(width * height * BITS_IN_BYTE);

    receivedBytes = srt_recvmsg(_sock, (char*)image.data(), image.size());
    if (receivedBytes <= 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to receive stream from Sharer");
    }

    image.resize(receivedBytes);
    return image;
}


Unrelated: Rather than making a buffer of char and then casting it to the type you actually want, make an instance of that type and cast it to a char when you pass it to the receive function. Anything can be cast to an array of char, but the reverse requires some hard guarantees. Either way, you may have some interpretation issues like endian to work out. In other words, receivedBytes = srt_recvmsg(_sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&width), sizeof(width));

The documentation at the github link sucks. I feel your pain.
